# Why is my ES6 webpack bundle larger when using default imports instead of named imports?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I am using OpenLayers 6 and I import parts of the library using this notation:

```
import { Map, View } from 'ol';
import { Vector as VectorSource } from 'ol/source';
import { Vector as VectorLayer } from 'ol/layer';
// More in other files [...]
```

When running `npm run dev` I get a **9MB** file for my project.

For testing purpose, I tried to replace these named imports by default imports:

```
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import View from 'ol/View';
import VectorSource from 'ol/source/Vector';
import VectorLayer from 'ol/layer/Vector';
```

Surprisingly, it reduced my bundled file to **6MB**!
It's 33% lighter, why is that? Shouldn't named imports be importing only required parts of modules?

**EDIT 1**

Following @Bergi comment, the library is available [here](https://openlayers.org/download/). I use the last version which is installed through `npm` : `v6.4.2`

**EDIT 2**

As pointed out by @felixmosh answer, running `npm run prod` seems to reduce the size difference. I get a difference of `1KB` from **886KB** to **885KB**.

Comment: Can you please post the contents of the `ol`, `ol/source` and `ol/layer` modules? Or at least link the library if it's open source? Otherwise we can't answer the question (without guessing only).

Comment: @Bergi I added the information you asked for to my question.

Comment: Thanks. That's weird, [`from 'ol'`](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/src/ol/index.js), [`from 'ol/source'`](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/src/ol/source.js) and [`from 'ol/layer'`](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/src/ol/layer.js) definitely should be tree-shakeable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tree shaking, is part of the minification process. In dev bundles this process is not applied.

Try to run in ["production"](https://webpack.js.org/guides/production/#specify-the-mode) mode, and compare the results.

Comment: Indeed, using npm run prod I get a difference of 1KB from 886KB to 885KB

Answer (score 2):

No, it shouldn't. It very depends on how internal libs are organized.

- If it uses `require` inside, the lib will not be shaked
- If it uses `import *` inside and uses this package, the whole `*` will be included
- Even! if it uses `import {name} from './names'` it still might not be tree-shaked

There is a good starting article about how tree shaking works and how to help it: https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/

Comment: "*If it uses `import *` inside*", then it will still use tree-shaking depending on the usage of the namespace object.

Comment: @Bergi Just did some tests with bundlesize. Maybe I am wrong, but it is not shaking if you are using at least ```import * as T from 'my-module'  ``` and then using something from it ```T.test()```. However, if you leave T unused, it is kicking it out